# Remove Focus from FpSpread

Tags: vb.net, farpoint

I have a problem removing the Focus from FpSpread to any other control in the same Form.

The real problem happens when opening another form while the old form is still opened, the focus remains at FpSpread in the old form.

any suggestions would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I did not get the solution but I got around the problem by disable the control, then re-enable it after that.

That solves the problem for me, but certainly it is not the right solution.